# Append stdout to file from terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I know using `command > file` will write the `stdout` of `command` to `file`, but is there a similar method to *append* to `file`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`command > file` will clobber the file and replace all data with stdout.

`command >> file` will append stdout to the file. (meaning the value of stdout is tacked to the end of the file).

Comment: I've edited Q and A to remove some <> for clarity. If you disagree, please revert my edit.

Comment: No, by all means.  I couldn't edit the question, so I just made my answer match!